# Create a local Scope for a 2010 Site collection in 2013 Search

Tags: enterprise-search, search-scope

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm with a specific site collection that requires a site collection level scoped search. however, I use SharePoint 2013 Search farm for my crawling and enterprise search site.

How do I pass the query from the SharePoint 2010 site collection to the SharePoint 2013 search to scope by site collection / path?

Do I need to create a whole new search page with a site collection specific result source and pass the query here? Or is it possible for the SharePoint 2013 farm to pick up the URL of the site the query was passed from?

TIA.